# Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^8.0.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-android

I am trying to upgrade the Cordova version to Cordova 9 (Cordova-android 8). I am getting error below while adding platform.

Please suggest any solution for this.

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^8.0.0
Adding ng-modules-scripts project...
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (Does not appear to implement platform Api.)
Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (The platform "ng-modules-scripts" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. ng-modules-scripts not supported.)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

Regards,

Tripaty Sahu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Cordova project somehow thinks it should add a `ng-modules-scripts` platform, which doesn't exist and as such can not be installed. You should check `cordova platform list` and clean your `config.xml` and `package.json` of this platform, possibly using `cordova platform rm ng-modules-scripts`.